# Are people allowed to use photos for commercial products that contain a logo?

Tags: photography, social-media

I was looking on unsplash when I came across this photo https://unsplash.com/search/gaming?photo=eCktzGjC-iU

Now, under unsplash's license agreement, people may use these photos for commercial purposes. However, this photo clearly contains the logo of a game company known as "playstation" on the controllers. So...is it actually legal to use that photo for commercial purposes? Or is unsplash about to get sued? Or...what?

Comment: I don't know about sued. But maybe receive a DMCA takedown request of that image if Sony were to become aware of it.